# Upgrade Nginx built-in in Kong API Gateway (CentOS 7)

Tags: nginx, centos7, upgrade, kong, kong-plugin

I have a problem with Nginx built-in when I install Kong API Gateway. My Kong is an old system and it has some modified plugins which were compatible with Kong version 1.2.2.

[image]

So, the Nginx module built-in in Kong is an old version and leads to security risk. This Kong is deployed for the production environment. And my question is "how can I upgrade the Nginx module only?" Because, If I upgrade Kong API Gateway, modified plugins may not be compatible with the new version.

Thank you.